# How to map inherited classes on database table with hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm working on a student management app, I'm confused with how to map different types of users that I have in my database with classes in Java, using inheritance. I have the tables "User", "Student" and "Teacher" as it follows:

[image]

I created the abstract class User:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = "user")
public abstract class User {

@Id
private int id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String email;
private String password;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String userType;
private boolean isAdmin;


public User(String fname, String lname, String email, String password, String address, String phone,
        String userType, boolean isAdmin) {
    //super();

    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}
```

The child class Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends User  {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int id;
private int grade;

public Student(int id, String fname, String lname, String email, String password, String address, String phone,
        String userType, int grade, boolean isAdmin) 
{
    super(fname, lname, email, password, address, phone, userType, isAdmin);

    this.grade=grade;
    this.id = id;
}
```

The class "Teacher" is in the same manner as "Student".

I got stuck on how to actually model the relationships using hibernate in order to do create, read, update or delete students from the database.

So far I have tried this method in a StudentDAO class, but it's not working and I'm really not confident if my modeling is alright:

```
@Transactional  
   public void listStudent( int id ){

    Student myStudent =null;

    Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);

     SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();

     Session session = sf.openSession();

     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

     myStudent = (Student)session.get(Student.class, id);

     System.out.println(myStudent);
```

I'm confused about how to use One-to-Many relationships as I'm seeing it as an inheritance.

How could I model this in the best way and how can I use hibernate to just use these basic operations on the database?

Comment: Given your database tables, the inheritance strategy you chose is not TABLE_PER_CLASS, but JOINED: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table

Comment: thanks, found useful info and for now looks good